# Using log4j JMSAppender with ActiveMQ - wire format timeout in debug level (client side)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, activemq-classic, appender

I'm trying to make a POC using log4j JMSappender and ActiveMQ. I successfully follow this example -> http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html

But this is for INFO level. I made some modification to use it in DEBUG level and my program and activeMQ can't exchange their wire format. Here are my log4j (client side)

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, jms
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
log4j.appender.jms.Threshold=DEBUG
```

When running my client, I have the wire format error.

Producer program:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ProducerDebug {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
{
    new ProducerDebug();
}

private ProducerDebug() throws InterruptedException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProducerInfo.class);

    while (true)
    {
        logger.debug("push DEBUG");
        logger.info("push INFO2");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
}
```

And the error message:

> log4j:ERROR Error while activating options for appender named [jms].
>   javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not
>   send his wire format.  at
>   org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1412)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1501)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:323)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createTopicSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:1134)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender.activateOptions(JMSAppender.java:218)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
>   at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:127)  at
>   org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)  at
>   awg.adb.producer.ProducerDebug.(ProducerDebug.java:13)  at
>   awg.adb.producer.ProducerDebug.main(ProducerDebug.java:9) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not
>   send his wire format.  at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
>   at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1387)
>   ... 17 more

I tried many things and I cannot understand why I have this error.

*For information*: I'm using
- ActiveMQ 5.12.1
- Log4j 1.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is due to AMQ logs if level is debug, one solution is to do the opposite like this :

> ```
> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
>
> ## Be sure that ActiveMQ messages are not logged to 'jms' appender
> log4j.logger.org.apache=INFO, stdout
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
>
> ## Configure 'jms' appender. You'll also need jndi.properties file in order to make it work
> log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
> log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
> log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://localhost:61616
> log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
> log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
> log4j.appender.jms.Threshold=DEBUG
> log4j.logger.your.package=jms
> ```

Comment: Thanks Hassen. I tried your example, changing 'log4j.logger.your.package=jms' by  'log4j.logger.your.package=DEBUG, jms' and it's working.